# Tag Cleanup: [convert]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup

There seem to be a small but steady stream of questions being tagged as [convert](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convert).

From what I can tell, they seem to range from power regulation ("convert 110V to 230V", etc.), to digital logic ("convert 32bit 2's complement..."), to programming ("convert float to hex"), and so fourth.

There is no wiki entry or usage for the tag, and given the varied use of it, it appears to be a completely meaningless tag.

There are <s>several instances of</s> now only two questions that are only tagged as [convert](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convert), both of which are closed. So deleting the tag now would only require those two to be retagged.

I'm of the opinion that [convert](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convert) should be consigned to the dustbin of tags never to see the light again. Thoughts?

Comment: Convert --> Power Conversion, Logic Conversion, Data Conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds reasonable to me. All [convert](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convert) tags have been removed. The tag will age away as long as no new questions get added.

If it continues to be created, we can blacklist the tag.